# Is it possible to get cc1plus.exe compiliing details on windows?

Tags: c++, windows

My app is tracing compiling process on windows via g++ or clang++. To compile a make project which trigger g++.

`myapp make` then the process tree looks:

```
├── make.exe
            ├── g++.exe
                    └── cc1plus.exe
```

Currently, I can get pid, parentid and sort of information about `make` unfortunately not `make` child processes. I am trying access those process via windows native API and win32api. `myapp` should run without admin privilege. I am not sure whether is possible to access `make`s child process and detailed compiling process information such as precompiling, linking etc.
There is `ETW API` but it forces admin privilege, so not I am looking for it.
Any information will help me really much.

PS: Via `ProcMon`, a windows tool, I can see whole details, but I want automate this process via my custom application. `ProcMon` require admin priv.

Comment: What's your end goal? To know all compiler invocations with exact flags?

Comment: Definitely and I am trying to capture compiling process, see all compiler options, flags and get all possible details about compiling, linking. @HolyBlackCat

Comment: I see at least following alternatives: 1. Add a bunch of debug flags to Make, to directly see what it invokes (`--trace`, ...?), 2. Make wrappers for compiler executables (that log the flags), put them into the PATH, then run Make.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat For 2. option, you mean a wrapper for i.e g++? or mind you explain more?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It should call the original `g++`, and also log the flags somewhere.

Comment: As far as I understood, `g++` invokes `cc1pus.exe` , do you think would it same way still work? @HolyBlackCat

Comment: What info exactly do you want to gather? Are `g++` flags enough, or do you also need `cc1plus` flags, and if yes, why?

Comment: Because `g++` flags I know which is mostly given before compiling processes. I want so see what is under the hood by getting `cc1plus.exe` flags and options. Actual job is done by `cc1plus.exe` @HolyBlackCat

Comment: @full_steak_developer Doing it reliably is not straightforward, and would require intercepting the CreateProcess calls from the parent process. Or, you could enable [process tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/manage/component-updates/command-line-process-auditing) in audit policies and get the information from the event log. Or, of course, rebuild a custom version of g++ with builtin logging.

Comment: @dxiv I want to make the tool generic, that's why rebuilding g++ is out, My intention was also to intercept CreateProcess calls but till nowI could get only 1.level process information, not child processes.

Comment: I would not be surprised if snooping on another process requires admin privileges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution via windows debug api. `WinBase.h` and if you change `DEBUG_PROCESS` to following options

```
#define DEBUG_PROCESS                     0x00000001
#define DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS           0x00000002
#define CREATE_SUSPENDED                  0x00000004
#define DETACHED_PROCESS                  0x00000008
```

up to the flag, you will retrieve the process informations.

```
if (!CreateProcess(0, const_cast<TCHAR *>(cmdLine.GetString()), 0, 0, true, DEBUG_PROCESS,
        0, 0, &startupInfo, &ProcessInformation))
    {
        std::ostringstream oss;
        oss << GetLastError();

    }
```